# sendDocument via Telegram bot

Tags: .net, powershell, telegram, telegram-bot

[sendDocument](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) requires **multipart/form-data**.

```
$path    = 'C:\file.txt'
$userId  = 12345
$token   = "ABC123"
$url     = "https://api.telegram.org/-/sendDocument?chat_id=+"

[net.servicepointmanager]::securityprotocol = 'ssl3,tls,tls11,tls12'
$url = $url.Replace("-",$token).Replace("+",$userId)
$Response = Iwr -Uri $url -Method Post -InFile $path -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
$Response.Content
```

But i got **Error:400**. How to properly send file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a file with a Telegram bot via PowerShell requires some more work.
This is an example of how to send a text document:

```
$payload = @{
    chat_id              = $ChatID
    document             = $FileURL
    caption              = $Caption
    parse_mode           = $ParseMode
    disable_notification = $DisableNotification.IsPresent
}

$invokeRestMethodSplat = @{
    Uri         = ("https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendDocument" -f $BotToken)
    Body        = (ConvertTo-Json -Compress -InputObject $payload)
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Method      = 'Post'
}

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod @invokeRestMethodSplat
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_
}
```

Another option I found is to make use of the `Form` param in PowerShell v6.1 or higher ([download](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) it from GitHub if needed); I found this raw example [here](https://www.itdroplets.com/automating-telegram-messages-with-powershell/):

```
$doc = "C:\something.txt"

$Uri = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$($BotToken)/sendDocument"
#Build the Form
$Form = @{
chat_id = $chatID
document = Get-Item $doc
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Form $Form -Method Post
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about it, but I recently read a bit on Telegram and I know there's a module called PoShGram that allows you to interact with it.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/techthoughts2/PoshGram)

At a glance looks like it may have the functionality you need. The read me says:

> The goal of this project to abstract that complexity away in favor of
> simple and direct PowerShell commands.